# Casper not starting with tools?

Tags: distrust

So when I select Casper as a character he is supposed to start with tools. When I select the tools icon under his picture the only choice I am given is to repair them.  How do I go about selecting his tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools that Casper starts with will not appear in inventory.  Instead when a tool is needed it will apply automatically.  An example being if Casper finds a broken item there will be a special icon of a fixing kit that can be applied to the item.

Comment: If this is indeed correct and an answer to your question, make sure to hit the check mark to mark it as answered :)